# How to access JIRA Software files in a docker image?

Tags: docker, jira

I deployed Jira in a Docker container.
`docker run --detach --publish 8080:8080 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software:latest`

I am accessing the files using:
`docker exec -t -i containerid /bin/bash`

But I am not able to see the files which are needed to edit. 
Supposedly for creating a maintenance splash page.
Ref : https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-create-a-maintenance-splash-page-290751207.html

Comment: `find / -name webapps`

Comment: /var/atlassian/jira

Comment: nope. the files aren't there like in a typical JIRA install. It resides by default in /opt/atlassian/jira/. But unable to see these files in docker filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documents](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-create-a-maintenance-splash-page-290751207.html) that you sent and location of the installation directory that you mentioned, you need to edit `/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml` file to edit the context section. Then edit `/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/web.xml` file to adding new error page.

Please note that you have to access those files via bin/bash from docker:

```
sudo docker exec -i -t  --user root containerid /bin/bash
```

Also [this](https://www.becodemonkey.com/2016/02/15/jira-docker-quicksetup/) has a good information as well.

Comment: Thanks. Found it.